# how to make dynamic associative array in Yii?

Tags: php, api, yii

I am trying to make a dynamic associtive array but the thing is it just save the last key-value pair how can i store all the key-value pairs?

```
foreach ($_POST as $var => $value) {



   // Does the model have this attribute? If not raise an error
        if ($model->hasAttribute($var))
            $model->$var = $value;
        elseif ($profile->hasAttribute($var)) {
            $storage = array($var => $value);//associative array
        } else {
            //var_dump ($var);
            $this->_sendResponse(500, sprintf('Parameter <b>%s</b> is not allowed for model <b>%s</b>', $var, $_GET['model']));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only below `error`:

```
 $storage = array($var => $value);//associative array
```

This line is creating a new `array` `$storage` every time, that's why you are getting only last `key` `value` pair.

Try this:

```
 $storage = array();// initialize it as array
 $storage[$var] = $value;// assign $value in $key index of $storage
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're always assigning the $storage to a new array instead of appending it.(Correct me if I'm wrong).

You should append the array this way.

```
 <?php

foreach ($_POST as $var => $value) {

    // Does the model have this attribute? If not raise an error
    if ($model->hasAttribute($var))
        $model->$var = $value;
    else if ($profile->hasAttribute($var)) {
        if (!is_array($storage))
            $storage = [];
        $storage[$var] = $value; //associative array
    } else {
        //var_dump ($var);
        $this->_sendResponse(500, sprintf('Parameter <b>%s</b> is not allowed for model <b>%s</b>', $var, $_GET['model']));
    }
}
```